# How would you have a single h1 tag with different styling for mobile and desktop? (Using bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to have a single h1 tag and have different styling for it.  I'm not sure if my css is the easiest way to do it?  I"m using bootstrap so maybe there is a more concise way?

I have the following HTML:

```
<h1>Hello I am an h1 tag</h1>
```

And following css:

```
h1 {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 32px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {  
  h1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to link [bootsrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#responsive-typography)

Responsive typography refers to scaling text and components by simply adjusting the root element’s font-size within a series of media queries. Bootstrap doesn’t do this for you, but it’s fairly easy to add if you need it.

Then Best way as I know is to use media queries.
 Viewport is another way for this. But not all browsers supports [link info](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html). Then most reliable way is to use media queires